# What type of constructor / method is used here?

Tags: c#, methods, constructor, c#-3.0, complex-numbers

I was looking for a way to calculate the addition of complex numbers and I saw this example but there is a part which I don't understand. this is the whole code for this class:

```
  class Complex
    {


       public  int real, imaginary;

        public Complex()
        {

        }

        public Complex(int tempReal , int tempImaginary)
        {
            real = tempReal;
            imaginary = tempImaginary;
        }

        public Complex addComp(Complex C1 , Complex C2)
        {
            Complex temp = new Complex();
            temp.real = C1.real + C2.real;
            temp.imaginary = C1.imaginary + C2.imaginary;

            return temp;

        }


}
```

The part where it is written :

```
 public Complex addComp(Complex C1 , Complex C2)
```

My question is first is this a constructor or method? and my next question is why is ***Complex*** written behind ***addComp***? how is that possible and what is the point of it?

Comment: addComp is a method that returns an object of type Complex and takes two Complex parameters: C1 and C2

Comment: I would make addComp static because no current instance data is used there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addComp` is a method, but a very badly written one!

Observations:

- `addComp` should *either* be `static` and take two parameters, or be non-`static` and take *one*; an instance method shouldn't ignore the `this` value, most times
- `addComp` should almost certainly be the binary `+` operator, which would be `static` in the above scenario (C# allows you to overload many operators, including `+`)
- `Complex` should probably be a `readonly struct`, not a `class` - with suitable operators and overloads, support for `IEquatable<Complex>`, etc
- `real` and `imaginary` should be *properties*, not public fields